# ytdl-core getInfo() function

Tags: node.js

so I was trying to get the metainfo from a youtube URL using ytdl in Node.js
here's the code I'm currently trying to get working :

```
ytdl.getInfo('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YQHsXMglC9A',{downloadURL: true},
  function(err, info) {
    if (err) throw err;
       console.log(info.title);
  }
);
```

So, this works fine and I get the title of the song. Now i'm trying to actually GET the info as in stocking it in a var for me to use later. And I can't get to manage it, I tried to return something from the callback methode or catching whatever getInfo() is giving but it keep saying it's 'undefined'.

If any of you have some ideas i'll be glad to try these.

Thanks, Lucas

Answer (score 3):

maybe do something like this

```
ytdl.getInfo('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YQHsXMglC9A',{downloadURL: true},
  function(err, info) {
    if (err) throw err;
       var songTitle = info.title //you can store it here
       console.log(songTitle);
  }
);
```

> When downloading a video/audio using `ytdl-core` use a event handler instead!
>   
>   The information will going to be fetched first, then audio/video is going to be downloaded.
>
> ```js
> ytdl(youtube_url)
> .on('info', (info) => {
>   console.log(info.title); // the video title
> });
> ```